# Prevent the "Confirm Navigation" dialog box from popping up on page leave

Tags: javascript

It seems this question has been asked a fair amount, but never resolved.

I want to prevent this dialog box (image attached) from appearing when leaving the page. The alert happens every time I change something in the form on this page, but the form is saving asynchronously, so no changes are actually "dirty" so to speak.

[image: Confirm Navigation dialog box]

I've tried a couple things found on stackoverflow and other sites, such as the following:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { 
    e.returnValue = '';
    return false;
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { 
    history.go(0);
}
```

Some advice on how to remove this would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: As requested, here is a code sample of what I'm trying. There is other code within the file, but nothing to do with it.

```
;(function($) {
    // doc ready
    $(function(){
        // Remove the alert
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What is your actual code ?

Comment: I have a document.ready listener surrounding my `window.onbeforeunload` assignments. That's the only moving parts regarding this issue. I'll add it to the question if you feel it's necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a working solution for this.

As mentioned, my form saves asynchronously, so the "You may lose changes" alert is not always accurate.

Now any link clicks are no longer having the dialog box appear. However this does not check against closing the tab/browser.

```
;(function($){
    var dontSubmit = false,
        $form = $('form#my-form');

    // Prevent the trigger a false submission on link click
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        dontSubmit = true;
        $form.trigger('submit');
    });

    $form.on('submit', function(event){
        if (dontSubmit) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        // Continue on as normal
    });
})(jQuery);
```